# Why do I constantly get lag spikes? (in minecraft but shown in google)

Tags: ping, gaming, lag, minecraft

```
Pinging Google.com [2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=17ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=19ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=31ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=25ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=23ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=46ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=14ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=18ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=13ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=222ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=81ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=27ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=17ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=16ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=18ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=33ms
Request timed out.
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=55ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=18ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=15ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=18ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=22ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=42ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=153ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=20ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=16ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=46ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=48ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=15ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=14ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=15ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=15ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=16ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=19ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=18ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=239ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=32ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=16ms
Request timed out.
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=36ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4006:808::200e: time=43ms
```

So when I play video games I constantly get lag spikes and so I pinged google and as you can see sometimes my ping goes to 200??? So basically that's the lag spikes, why does it happen? You can see that the ping is normal before and after the lag spikes.

EDIT:
Another test:

```
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=117
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=36ms TTL=117
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=117
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=117
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=60ms TTL=117
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=117
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=186ms TTL=117
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=117
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=117
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=121ms TTL=117
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=117
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=117
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=117
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=117
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=62ms TTL=117
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=117
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=117
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=117
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=117
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=117
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=117
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=428ms TTL=117
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=285ms TTL=117
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=117
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=117
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=11ms TTL=117
```

Comment: are u using wifi or lan cable?

Comment: @DarkBeccio wifi? it's a router?